# Overwrite hive schema metadata without dropping and creating

Tags: hive

Say I have a predefined Hive table with partitions loaded to it.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE t1
(
 c1 STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY ( dt STRING )
LOCATION...

ALTER TABLE t1 ADD PARTITION ( dt = '2017-01-01' )
```

Now I got a new text representing the schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE t1
(
 user_id STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY ( dt STRING )
LOCATION...
```

If I drop and then recreate the table, I'll lose partitions info.
I am looking for a way to redefine the columns schema part without manual add/remove/rename columns ( not a one time thing, trying to automate a schema update process ).

Comment: The question is not clear. Please illustrate your scenario using a small data sample.

Comment: (1) Data samples are a a good base for us to generate a demo and for you to verify that the suggested solution answers your needs. (2) Does the schema change relevant to old partitions or only new partitions? (3) what is the problem with add/remove/rename?

Comment: 1) The question is only about metadata 2) Only the columns ( not partition columns ) can change. 3) Trying to automate a schema update process, so manually rename/delete/add columns is doable but requires more work and more error prone...Thanks!

Comment: you can alter column name from c1 to user_id,  ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 user_id  STRING;

Comment: What is the problem to compare schemes and generate a series of  add/remove/rename columns operations automatically?

Comment: While this is indeed possible I was looking ( and actually found! ) a cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do 'almost' what I needed:

Hive supports

```
REPLACE COLUMNS
```

Which means I can replace all old columns with new ones.